# Using $subtract on array of objects in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider the collection

```
{   "name": "Student1",   "marks": [
    {
      "subject": "Subject1",
      "marks": 12
    },
    {
      "subject": "Subject2",
      "marks": 15
    },
    {
      "subject": "Subject3",
      "marks": 20
    }   ] }
```

I am trying to perform $subtract on marks. I tried the aggregation as below.

```
db.mycoll.aggregate(
[
      {
        "$addFields": {
          diff: {$subtract:["$marks.0.marks","$marks.1.marks","$marks.2.marks"]}
        }
      }
    ]
)
```

The approach doesnt seems to be working. I am getting an error

```
"Couldn't execute query: cant $subtract a array from a array"
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show us your expected JSON output?

Comment: subtraction usually involves two values.  what exactly are you trying to compute here?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to leverage the use of **[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce)** operator to achieve the desired output as follows:

```
db.mycoll.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "diff": { 
                "$reduce": { // expression returns difference
                    "input": "$marks",
                    "initialValue": 0,
                    "in": { "$subtract": ["$$this.marks", "$$value"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```